# AS app emulator crashing rendering problems

Tags: android

I am building an app for android, and so far things are going well.
The app runs fine in the emulator, until I decided to use a picture from the web, download it as .png and use it as my background image in the login screen.

In the xml code I simply, in the linearLayout set the background like this:

```
android:background="@drawable/login"
```

Which should be completely fine(login is the login.png file).

There is an error message saying

```
Rendering problems
-Paint.setShadowLayer is not supported
```

When I launch the app, the emulator starts and tries to start the app, however it immidiately quits and says "unfortunately, "appname" has stopped".

So the problem is the background image, but what can it be? Is using an image just like this directly a very naive method?

Thanks in advance!
[Here is an image of the login activity before launching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Arxg.jpg)

Logcat error message:

12-16 19:53:39.538 2218-2218/com.example.koenraad.emergencyapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.koenraad.emergencyapp, PID: 2218
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.koenraad.emergencyapp/com.example.koenraad.Exigentia.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
                                                                                     at com.example.koenraad.Exigentia.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:72)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
                                                                                     at com.example.koenraad.Exigentia.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:72) 
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
                                                                                     at com.example.koenraad.Exigentia.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:72) 
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 82944012 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM
                                                                                     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                                     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                                     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
                                                                                     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                                                                                     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
                                                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
                                                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
                                                                                     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.(View.java:3948)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:573)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java:203)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java:199)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java:195)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
                                                                                     at com.example.koenraad.Exigentia.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:72) 
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not an error it just tell you that the preview of code will not be the same as output

the problem must be something else,it could be the resolution of the image ,try to get the error from the logcat while testing the app

Comment: the logcat is in the android monitor  look at this picture

Comment: https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-0DsYPhUE6UQ/V1TinyhuAwI/AAAAAAAAANQ/0YYykVQZTCY4WxoVcE7SNao0VZpNPg3uACLcB/s1600/error15.png

Comment: thnx. I added another link in my main question. Do you understand anything=?

Comment: its not complet  just copy and past the error its better

Comment: there. Looks very long

Comment: you have OutOfMemoryError, the problem is the picture you added  is very large it takes to much memory  try convert it to a smaller one  make the size of the layout

Comment: Thanks. The dimension is 1920x1200, is that too big? Or is the problem its size, which is 4 mb?

Comment: it could be both but more likely the size  try to make it approximately  400x800 and 500kb

Comment: How should I do this? Thnx for helping out a newb!

Comment: no problem , try this online image resizer  http://resizeimage.net/   and keep it png  i hope it works for you .